# Python SDK can't find salesforceSoapApi

Tags: python, python-3.x, salesforce, virtualenv

Salesforce Python SDK appears to be correctly installed in a virtenv:

```
(venv-python3) pixmaclt61:venv-python3 ddow$ sudo easy_install salesforce-python-sdk
Searching for salesforce-python-sdk
Best match: salesforce-python-sdk 0.1.3
Processing salesforce_python_sdk-0.1.3-py3.5.egg
salesforce-python-sdk 0.1.3 is already the active version in easy-install.pth

Using /Users/ddow/venv-python3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/salesforce_python_sdk-0.1.3-py3.5.egg
Processing dependencies for salesforce-python-sdk
Finished processing dependencies for salesforce-python-sdk
```

But when I try to import it:

```
ddow$ python
Python 3.5.0 (v3.5.0:374f501f4567, Sep 12 2015, 11:00:19) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import salesforce
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/ddow/venv-python3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/salesforce_python_sdk-0.1.3-py3.5.egg/salesforce/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/ddow/venv-python3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/salesforce_python_sdk-0.1.3-py3.5.egg/salesforce/api.py", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'salesforceSoapApi'
```

I've  checked for the module and it looks like it's there:

```
ddow$ cd salesforce
(venv-python3) pixmaclt61:salesforce ddow$ ls
__init__.py     exception.py        sObject.py      salesforceSoapApi.py    version.py
__pycache__     httpClient.py       salesforceApi.py    urlResources.py
api.py          login.py        salesforceRestApi.py    utils.py
```

Any help please? :D

Thanks,

Dan

Comment: Can you manually import once you launch the python interpreter from the salesforce directory? (something like import salesforceSoapApi.py)

Comment: Yes, but then I ran into all kinds of other problems.  I thought this was supposed to by Python 3 compatible, but apparently not.  Thanks.